# Remote Interactive Push Notifications - HOW?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

**TL;DR How do I send interactive notifications through Expo’s Push API**

Please provide the following:

SDK Version: 40
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): All
Using the following code and I have created a category and using `getNotificationCategoriesAsync`, confirmed its existence.

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";

// Set up Category
  Notifications.setNotificationCategoryAsync("basic", [
    { identifier: "Yes", buttonTitle: "Yes " },
    { identifier: "No", buttonTitle: "No " },
  ])

// Check category is there
  Notifications.getNotificationCategoriesAsync().then((categories) => {
  console.log(categories)});

// Get experienceId
  experienceId = Constants.manifest.id;
  console.log(experienceId);
```

On the API side, I have used the request below and replaced @username/appName with what was logged above (experienceId). I have tried this with real devices and simulators for both ios and android and even though the notification does send, it is missing the interactive aspect.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send" -d '{
  "to": "ExponentPushToken[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]",
  "title":"hello",
  "body": "world",
  "_category":"@username/appName:basic",
}'
```

I have also tried replacing “_category” with “categoryId” or “categoryIdentifier” or “category”. None of which has worked. Has anyone been able to successfully do this! If so how! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close, the experienceId and category are joined with a hyphen "-". Looking at the source code on iOS you can see the format string:

https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/fd47709156ed218cd5a8c5093df113918bdb2700/ios/versioned-react-native/ABI40_0_0/Expo/ExpoKit/Core/UniversalModules/EXNotifications/ABI40_0_0EXScopedNotificationBuilder.m#L33

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send" -d '{
  "to": "ExponentPushToken[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]",
  "title":"hello",
  "body": "world",
  "_category":"@username/appName-basic",
}'
```

Comment: Thank you Dillon, this works and completely made my week after many painful days of debugging. Have a great new year!

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working on android, any idea why?

Comment: How are your channels setup? I know android needs extra setup: `if (Platform.OS === "android") {
  Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("basic", {
   name: "Basic",
   importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
   sound: "default",
   vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 500, 250],
  });`

Comment: I have not tested it on android, but looking at the java code, it looks like it may be different from the iOS: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/78cc872e23796b0617ce828994a75830f701d79c/android/versioned-abis/expoview-abi40_0_0/src/main/java/abi40_0_0/host/exp/exponent/modules/api/notifications/ScopedNotificationsIdUtils.java

Comment: Expo hasn't really documented the "category" api yet. So I'm not sure if `"_category"` param in curl is iOS specific, and Android requires something else? It may be worth bringing up with Expo on how to use categories, because I can't find it documented anywhere.